# Is it possible to defer evaluation of function literals with varying numbers/types of parameters?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a set of functions which all have a common return type, but different numbers and types of parameters, for example:

```
def find(id: Int): MyVal = {}
def like(part: String, max: Int): MyVal = {}
def first(): MyVal = {}
```

all of these need to pass through a common validation procedure, and what I would like to do is to encapsulate that logic into a single function, which then takes any of the methods above (and others with the same return type) as an additional argument:

```
def checkAndEvaluate(token: String, func: () => MyVal): MyVal = {
    validateToken(token) match {
        case Pass => func()
        case Fail => // Do some error handling
    }
}
```

In other words, I would like to pass function literals, *together with their needed parameters*, and then only have them evaluate from *inside* the receiving function in the event that the validation passes.

Is this possible to do in Scala, and if so, what would be the preferred way of achieving it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to use `function` at all, all you need is Scala parameter `call-by-name`:[More about `call-by-name` parameter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/functions_call_by_name.htm)

A short example:

```
scala> def invoke(id: Int): Int = { println("invoked"); 0 }
invoke: (id: Int)Int

scala> def run(x : Int, i: => Int): Int = x match {
     |   case 0 => i
     |   case 1 => -1
     | }
run: (x: Int, i: => Int)Int

scala> run(0, invoke(100))
invoked
res2: Int = 0

scala> run(1, invoke(100))
res3: Int = -1
```

Based on your codes:

```
scala> def find(id: Int): Int = 0
find: (id: Int)Int

scala> def like(part: String, max: Int): Int = 1
like: (part: String, max: Int)Int

scala> def first(): Int = 2
first: ()Int

scala> def checkAndEval(token: String, lazyEval : => Int): Int = token.size match {
     |   case 0 => lazyEval
     |   case _ => -1
     | }
checkAndEval: (token: String, lazyEval: => Int)Int

scala> checkAndEval("", like("xxx", 0))
res0: Int = 1

scala> checkAndEval("err", like("xxx", 0))
res1: Int = -1
```

Comment: I like your approach, and it works, however, I'm not a fan of the call-by-name semantics in scala as you don't know it's happening when you call the function, only in the function definition. Ran into problems with this a few times in production code because the laziness was none obvious. It is more concise though, which I do appreciate :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do in scala, here's an example:

```
  checkAndEvaluate("token", () => find(1))
  checkAndEvaluate("token", () => like("like", 1))
  checkAndEvaluate("token", () => first())
```

None of the functions will be called until you call `func()`, if you call it at all.